# How to silently install dmg file in mac os x system (using shell script)?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I have used the following command for dmg file attach and detech

```
hdiutil attach installer.dmg 
hdiutil detach installer.dmg
```

in the dmg file it contains test.app 
GUI mode installation, i can drag the test.app to application location

What i need is when i double-click the script, dmg containing the app should install automatically to

application location in mac os x after that terminal window should automatically closed

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, a shell script like the following should do the job:

#### install_app.sh

```
#/bin/sh

VOLUME=`hdiutil attach $1 | grep Volumes | awk '{print $3}'`
cp -rf $VOLUME/*.app /Applications
hdiutil detach $VOLUME
```

and you can run it that way:

```
% install_app.sh ~/Downloads/MyApp.dmg
```

be aware that I'm doing no argument checking in that little script, and that any existing app with the same name will get overwritten.

HTH

Comment: Be careful to handle pathnames with spaces! Make that `hdiutil attach "$1"`, `cp -rf "$VOLUME/*.app" /Applications` and `hdiutil detach "$VOLUME"` (add `"` around variable references). I'm not sure about how to fix the `awk` call, though.

Comment: what is $l in this script ? what will be its value

Comment: It's not `$l` but `$1`, if you do not see the difference, use a better monospace font! That variable contains the first argument passed to the script.

Comment: Hi. If you change the awk '{print $3}' to a cut -f 3, it will include a folder that has spaces. Edit: Updated the above.

Comment: `hdiutil attach $DMG | grep /Volumes | sed 's/.*\/Volumes\//\/Volumes\//'`